# Set the Selected value of listbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I initially add some string objects in a `listBox` and afterwards I want to set the Item that is selected:

```
List <string> CustName = new List<string>();

....///add items to CustName///...      

listBox1.ItemsSource = CustName;
string selection = "myselection" ///this string is contained in CustName      
listBox1.SelectedValue = selection;
```

However tha above doesn't work  seens the selected Item is the first item of the `listBox` and not the one I try to set...

Comment: Have you tried `listBox1.SelectedIndex = indexOfMySelection`?

Answer (score 1):

why not use binding, something like this.
XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding CustName} SelectedItem={Binding MySelectedItem} />
```

then have a property

```
private string mySelectedItem;
public string MySelectedItem
{
get{return mySelectedItem;}
set
{
mySelectedItem=value;
RaisePropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
}
```

if you want to set the SelectedItem manually in code, then just do MySelectedItem=yourItem;

Don't forget to set DataSource of the listbox and implement INotifyPropertChanged

Answer (score 0):

**XAML:**

```
  <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" Height="100" Margin="310,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
  </Grid>
```

**CodeBehind.cs**

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> CustName = new List<string>();
        CustName.Add("test1");
        CustName.Add("test2");
        CustName.Add("myselection");


        listBox1.ItemsSource = CustName;
        string selection = "myselection";  
        listBox1.SelectedItem = selection;
    }
```

Comment: It was typo I fixed...I have also tried with SelectedItem but no result

Comment: @apomene check modified answer